# Instance variables not picked up in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a **GamesController** that has a **success** method. The method is supposed to find a (game) booking object using a supplied parameter and allow the view to display information relating to the booking object. Doing this gives me an error, suggesting that the **@booking** instance variable is Nil. My setup is below:

**GamesController**

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController

    def success
        @booking = Booking.find_by(session_id: params[:session_id])
    end

end
```

**success.html.erb**

```
<h1>Booking reference: <%= @booking.reference %></h1>
<p>Thank you for your booking</p>
```

---

I'm able to work around this by creating a separate method, **set_booking**, which finds the booking and delivers it to the success function via a before action. My amended setup is:

**GamesController**

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController

    before_action :set_booking, :only => [ :success ]

    def success
    end

    def set_booking
        @booking = Booking.find_by(session_id: params[:session_id])
    end

end
```

**success.html.erb (unchanged)**

```
<h1>Booking reference: <%= @booking.reference %></h1>
<p>Thank you for your booking</p>
```

**My question:** What I don't understand is, why is the booking object not available in the view without the before_action. I thought that making it an instance variable with '@' would suffice - is there a convention that I'm missing here?

Thank you!

Comment: There's no reason why it shouldn't be available when defining in the action itself. Did you pass the correct `session_id` when testing the first one?

Comment: Thanks @Anuj. 

I've just double checked and it definitely doesn't work. I wonder if it has something to do with the naming conventions? `@booking` not `@game` or similar? Or success not being a standard resource?

Comment: I also believe that you have a typo somewhere or something like that. Otherwise it should totally work. I assume you condensed your code a lot (which is not bad per se), or is that really the complete code?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your feedback. I was so confused by the behaviour so I rewrote the controller (yes, it was condensed to make it cleaner). It then worked - but I wasn't fully satisfied because I couldn't find the typo.

In short, there wasn't a typo but rather the success function was defined twice ‍♂️ Glad to have figured it out eventually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your feedback.

I was so confused by the behaviour so I rewrote the controller (yes, it was condensed to make it cleaner). It then worked - but I wasn't fully satisfied because I couldn't find the typo. In short, there wasn't a typo but rather ***the success function was defined twice*** ‍♂️ Glad to have figured it out eventually

Comment: you are welcome. Please accept your own answer or close the question for future users.